# BackgroundWorker - C#

Tags: c#, list

I am developing a multithreading application using BackroundWorker. In the Do_Work method I call another method, in that method I add a lot of data into a list using a while-statement. My goal is to add all the data that in the list to show in a GridView. How can I do that so every time data adds to the list, the gridview uppdates? Instead of waiting until that the while-statement has finished running. When the while-statment adds a value to the list, the value inserts into the gridview?

It must be in the ProgressChanged, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Have you looked at the example [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onprogresschanged.aspx)?

Comment: I have, but I dont realy know how to right so that my list values adds to the grdiview :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.  I have a class called WorkerThread that does the work we want

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
   // create the background worker object
   BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

   // tell the background worker it can be cancelled and report progress
   _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

   // a worker thread object where the actual work happens
   WorkerThread thread = new WorkerThread();

   // add our event handlers
   _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler( thread.RunWorkerCompleted );
   _worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler( thread.ProgressChanged );
   _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler( thread.DoWork );

   // start the worker thread
   _worker.RunWorkerAsync();

   // wait for it to be completed
   while( !_worker.CancellationPending )
   {
      // sleep for a second
      Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
    }

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Now in the WorkerThread class

```
public class WorkerThread
{
    public void DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
    {
       //get a handle on the worker that started this request
       BackgroundWorker workerSender = sender as BackgroundWorker;

       // loop through 10 times and report the progress back to the sending object
       for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
       {
          // tell the worker that we want to report progress being made
          workerSender.ReportProgress( i );
          Thread.Sleep( 100 );
       }

       // cancel the thread and send back that we cancelled
       workerSender.CancelAsync();
       e.Cancel = true;

    }

    public void RunWorkerCompleted( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
    {
       Console.WriteLine( "Worker Done!!" );          
    }

    public void ProgressChanged( object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e )
    {
      // print out the percent changed
      Console.WriteLine( e.ProgressPercentage );
    }
}
```

I am using a custom class, you could use a method in your class that is creating the background worker.  Just modify the code in the ProgressChanged event.

Comment: How can I do that instead of you console.Writeline in ProgressChanged method add my datagridview datasource to a list??

Answer (score 2):

My method was to create a class that would hold any data that I am passing back and forth. When you call `ReportProgress` it will require the percentage increment and an object argument. You put your class into this object argument, and from the `ProgressChanged` event this object is made available through the `ProgressChangedEventArgs`. You can then read this data, input it into the control you are wanting to update and then call the `Refresh()` method on that control to update it in the UI without freezing the interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx

**Edit:** (psuedocode, untested)

```
private List<Customer> _customerList = new List<Customer>();

protected void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MyDataGridView.DataSource = _customerList;  // Here is where you'll set your data source and bindings
    Load_Customer_Method();
}

private void Load_Customer_Method()
{
    int totalCustomers = 20;
    int currentCustomer = 1;

    for(currentCustomer = 1; currentCustomer <= totalCustomers; currentCustomer++)
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        // Configure customer

        ReportProgress(100*currentCustomer/totalCustomers, c);
    }
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Customer addedCustomer = (Customer)e.UserState;
    _customerList.Add(addedCustomer);  // If bindings are set, this update is automatic
    MyDataGridView.Refresh();  // Force a refresh of the screen for this grid to make
                               // it appear as if the grid is populating one object at
                               // a time. 
}
```

Comment: I do save the data into a class that I use for passing data back and forth.

Comment: @Lars: So what's the question then? This object is made immediately available as a property of the ProgressChangedEventArgs and is accessible from the ProgressChanged event.

Comment: In my Do_Work method I call another method that adds all the data into the list. In that method runs a while-statement that adds the data into the list. How do I do then? Iam realy sorry but iam little bit confused :S

Comment: @Lars: If you have an external method you're calling from Do_Work to populate your data list, this same method can be called from within the ProgressChanged event. You should be able to take whatever data is coming back in your class and just append it to the already existing items.

Comment: In my Do_Work, I call the method that adds the value, this method dose not return eny data, it just adds the data to a list. Then I call bakgroundworker.ReportProgress(0, cosutmers). Then in ProgressChanged, I create an instanse of the customer class where all the data is like this Customer customers = e.UserState as Customer. After that i call the method that binds the gridview.DataSource to the list. What do I do wrong?

Comment: @Lars: Are you saying your `Do_Work` method is creating a list of customers?

Comment: Yes, when I press a button down, I run bgw..RunWorkerAsync(), then i my Do_Work I call the method that adds all the costumers into a list.

Comment: @Lars: I added a code snippet into my answer that is psuedocode of how this would work.

Answer (score 2):

Add a progress changed event handler to your worker

In your Do_Work method

```
   BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

   worker.ReportProgress(0, new DataObject())
```

In your progess handler

```
  DataObject data (DataObject)e.UserState;
  yourList.Add(data);
```

If you know how far you are along you can send the actual done count in ReportProgess instead of 0.

Comment: In my Do_Work method I call another method that adds all the data into the list. In that method runs a while-statement that adds the data into the list. How do I do then? Iam realy sorry but iam little bit confused :S

Comment: In my Do_Work, I call the method that adds the value, this method dose not return eny data, it just adds the data to a list. Then I call bakgroundworker.ReportProgress(0, cosutmers). Then in ProgressChanged, I create an instanse of the customer class where all the data is like this Customer customers = e.UserState as Customer. After that i call the method that binds the gridview.DataSource to the list. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read on the backgroundworker. You have all the info and example there :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

All you will need to do is to pass your item as parameter in ReportProgress and in the event ProgressChanged add your item in your grid.