# Timer being interrupted

Tags: c#, .net, timer, stream

I have a problem with the Timer in a Windows Forms app. The archiver that needs the Timer to note the time of archiving. However something is interrupting the timer?

I suspect it is the streams. Any advice on what could cause the timer to be interrupted?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int timerCounter = 0;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = 1000; 
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); 

        // code for archiving, streams

        timer.Stop(); 

        MessageBox.Show("Archive was created! :)");
    }

    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label7.Text = (++timerCounter).ToString();
    }
```

}

Comment: Please describe the problem you are actually facing along with error message or similar.

Comment: i think you should add timer in background_woker, the thread gets busy in archiving process!

Comment: when I try to start my timer first, timer stops when there is stream.

Comment: I suggest you to do "Archieving process" in Background_worker , so the timer_tick will not stuck.

Comment: Maybe useful to add in the code for // code for archiving, streams

Answer (score 7):

The Windows Forms timer is not multi-threaded. That means, the tick event only fires when the program is idle (receives messages through its message queue). In your program this doesn't seem to be the case. You can easily check this: If your UI is responsive during the archiving process, then the `Forms.Timer` runs also and the problem is somewhere else. If it is not responsive, then the form (and the timer as a consequence) is blocked (no messages in the application's message queue are processed).

There are two ways out of this:

1. To do what you want to achieve, you can use `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`, as they run asynchronously in the background. The UI still won't update (the timer method would stop), however, as the UI is still blocked (see above).
2. The other way is to use a background worker for the archiving process (this then runs in another thread). The UI and the timer keep responsive.

Comment: As I know nothing about your archiving process, the only valid reply is: By searching Google/StackOverflow on `BackgroundWorker` samples and adapting them to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should to know that long running operation should be performent in another than UI thread. So, you create a proccessing thread which do archiving itself and also it notifies UI by using Control.Invoke method. [msdn description of Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Initially i thought that you are performing your archiving in the background thread. If it is not so - you should consider using BackgroundWorker for executing the operation in the background (here's [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275177/backgroundworker-c-sharp)).

Here is the simpler solution, though:

Try to add `Application.DoEvents()` in your *button2_Click* handler (I guess you are waiting for 'streams' to finish the archiving). For timer to fire and for label7 to redraw its new text value the redraw event should be processed.

Comment: Won't happen as the timer won't fire. *If* you really want to use `DoEvents`, don't call it in the timer event, but in the code that does the archiving.

Comment: You should not use Application.DoEvents(), until it is extremely necessary . Because if application will have too many message in message-queue it will get busy executing those messages first ! Try to avoid using Application.DoEvents()! Instead of this try using multithreading

Comment: @Sunny Yes it's true, however sometimes it is much easier to crash your application with incorrect multithreading than with adding single 'DoEvents' call. In fact I don't think that in this case the archiver utility will have 'too many messages' in queue. The job is done in the background an Forms only wait for the process to complete.

Comment: Jeff Atwood's posts on Do Events: [Is DoEvents Evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html) and [Is DoEvents Evil, Revisited](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/is-doevents-evil-revisited.html).

Answer (score -1):

The use of timer here is unnecessary why don t you just use `TimeSpan`

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    // code for archiving, streams

    TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - startTime;

    MessageBox.Show("Archive was created! in " + diff.TotalSeconds + " seconds.");
}
```

Comment: OP wants to show progress while performing archive operation. Not just time elapsed.

Comment: how can it be related to ticker it s just counting time not a progress. It should be handled by in the block where OP commented as "//code for archiving, streams".

Comment: yes i need to show how long archiving runs. for example : 00:00:44

Comment: so your answer is the TimeSpan and you can write your format like diff.ToString("hh:mm:ss");